# Plot data string against integer python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

So I have dataframe like this:
[image]

My question, is it possible to do plotting `Category` against `Read Count` from my dataframe? And it will automatically sums up `Read Count` values if the `Category` is same, Like `Megapolitan` read count is 142262(87612+54650).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
df.groupby('Category')['Read Count'].sum().plot.bar()
```

Output:

[image]

**EDIT**: Based on comments:

```
df.groupby('Category')['Read Count'].sum().sort_values(ascending=True).plot.barh()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks it works! But how to make the chart ascending? Because after I tried it will gave an error `AttributeError: 'Rectangle' object has no property 'ascending'`. And I'm using `barh()`

Comment: See the edit, I think that's what you want. Or remove the `ascending=True` if you want Megapolitan on top.